# Menus items appear twice in admin menu

Tags: routes

The menus menu items appear twice as shown in the image below. I have tried to disable menu items in the Management menu which had no effect. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: How can someone identify the problem with this screenshot ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the cause of admin_menu.module.  Upgrade it to the the most current version; it will be fixed.  That problem was fixed one or two versions ago.

Comment: This is what fixed the same problem for me a while back. Also uninstalling admin menu, reinstalling it, then clearing the cache twice seemed to help on another occasion if I remember rightly